# 'account is sensitive and cannot be delegated'

Tags: active-directory, delegation

This setting is part of the 'account' dialog on an active directory domain account. This setting is recommended for privileged accounts.

I dont know much about this setting but running into an issue where i have two domains which trust each other, but i cant move a user account from one domain to the other when this setting i checked. I suspect it's because im connected to one of the domains but my credentials cant be used/transferred on the destination domain through delegation.

Is there a way to do this cross-domain move without using delegation, so i can keep this box checked?

How would i authenticate to both domains so the authentication is not done through delegation(which this setting prohibits)?

Comment: In what context? What kind of account, what kind of software? Versions? etc.

Comment: Ah, probably should have stated, this is a windows active directory domain account. The checkbox is as described in the title, on the 'accounts' tab of the account.

Comment: This is dependent on the method and tool used for moving the account.

Comment: It honestly sounds like a situation where you could be using a service account to perform the delegated task in the remote domain. Just as one idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.